# Which dark SciFi Fate Core settings other then Mindjammer exist?

Tags: fate-core, campaign-settings

I want a list of dark SciFi Fate Core settings.

I have already looked Mindjammer, which can be played with a grim mood in mind.

Are there anything else?

Comment: Hello, Sorry, we don't serve questions of this sort - "shopping" or "recommendation" questions, a kind of list question - here on RPG.SE.

Answer (score -2):

***[Transhumanity's Fate](http://www.eclipsephase.com/releases/transhumanitys-fate)*** is an adaptation of ***Eclipse Phase*** to the system, and it's generally characterised as dark. Apocalypse happened, and some of humanity survived. But the things that were involved in it are still out there, they're insidious and often very tempting, and overall the uncaring and hostile universe is not conducive to humanity's survival. Also, depending on definitions, humanity changed so much that it may or may not be still considered humanity.